# How to get type file and if condition using yii framework

Tags: php, excel, yii, powerpoint

i have project to preview powerpoint presentation or excel file. This is my code

```
    <?php
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
if (count($dataJadwal) > 0) {
// get a reference to the path of PHPExcel classes
    $phpExcelPath = Yii::getPathOfAlias('ext.phpexcel.Classes.PHPExcel');

// Turn off our amazing library autoload
    spl_autoload_unregister(array('YiiBase', 'autoload'));
    Yii::import('ext.phpexcel.Classes.PHPExcel', true);
    spl_autoload_register(array('YiiBase', 'autoload'));
//
// making use of our reference, include the main class
// when we do this, phpExcel has its own autoload registration
// procedure (PHPExcel_Autoloader::Register();)
    include($phpExcelPath . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'IOFactory.php');

//require_once("D:\server/www/cls/PHPExcel.php");
//require_once("D:\server/www/cls/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php");
    $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load(urldecode($dataJadwal[0]['fileJadwal']));

    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'HTML');
//$objWriter->save('example.html');
$objWriter->writeAllSheets();
    $objWriter->save('php://output');

    Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('cje', "$('table').addClass('table table-bordered table-condensed table-hover')");
} else {
    ?>
   <div class="alert alert-danger" style="width: 50%; font-size: 32px; margin: 0 auto; margin-top: 20%; text-align: center"><i class="fa fa-3x fa-warning"></i>Tidak ada data.</div>
    <?php
}
?>
```

I don't know how to get extension file that have been uploaded and if the extension is excel file than the code run phpexcel plugin but if the extension is powerpoint file, code will run plugin phppowerpoint.

this is my table[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9lzZ.png)